# asyncio.gather() - task.cancelled() is False after task.cancel()

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, python-asyncio

After cancelling an `asyncio.gather()` task i would expect `task.cancelled()` to return `True` but instead it returns `False`.

**Questions**

---

- Is this expected?
- While `Future.cancel()` sets `self._state = _CANCELLED` the overridden `_GatheringFuture.cancel()` does not set `self._state`. *(`task.cancelled()` uses `task._state`)*. Is this by design?

**Example**

---

```py
def test_gather_cancellation_cancels_children_but_not_itself():

    # loop
    loop = new_event_loop()
    set_event_loop(loop)

    # create tasks and schedule them in gather
    task_child = ensure_future(sleep(1.0, result=1))
    task_gather = gather(task_child, return_exceptions=False)

    # assert nothing cancelled/done
    assert task_child.cancelled() is False
    assert task_gather.cancelled() is False
    assert task_child.done() is False
    assert task_gather.done() is False

    # cancel and await finishing of children
    assert task_gather.cancel() is True
    try:
        with pytest.raises(CancelledError):
            loop.run_until_complete(task_gather)
    finally:
        set_event_loop(None)
        loop.close()

    # assert all cancelled
    assert task_child.cancelled() is True

    # SURPRISING ASSERTION HERE:
    # surprisingly this is False because the the internal
    # task._state variable is not set in overridden
    # _GatheringFuture.cancel()
    assert task_gather.cancelled() is False  # this is surprising, expected True

    # assert all done
    assert task_child.done() is True
    assert task_gather.done() is True
```

```
============================= test session starts =============================
platform win32 -- Python 3.8.3rc1, pytest-5.4.2, py-1.8.1, pluggy-0.13.1 -- 
collecting ... collected 1 item

tests/gather/test_gather.py::test_gather_cancellation_cancels_children_but_not_itself PASSED [100%]
```

**Docs**

---

The [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather) mention this:

> If gather() is cancelled, all submitted awaitables (that have not completed yet) are also cancelled. **If any Task or Future from the aws sequence is cancelled, it is treated as if it raised CancelledError – the gather() call is not cancelled in this case.** This is to prevent the cancellation of one submitted Task/Future to cause other Tasks/Futures to be cancelled.

However, it seems to me that this would apply **only when gathered tasks are cancelled from outside**! When running cancel() explicitly on the `gather()` task *(and therefore its children)*, then it seems surprising that `task.cancelled()` is `False`. Therefore i'm not sure if the case described in the docs applies here.

Comment: It seems like a bug. If you've called `cancel()` and `done()` is true, I would expect `cancelled()` to also return true.

Comment: After digging into the code, there seem no way to setting `_state = _CANCELLED` in `_GatheringFuture`. Bug or decision?

Answer (score 2):

**For anyone interested:** I have filed a bug report on *bugs.python.org*. The issue has been reviewed by asyncio core devs and is generally regarded as a lower priority bug. I also created a PR to fix it which awaits review on low priority.

- [Bug report 40894](https://bugs.python.org/issue40894)
- [PR](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/20686)

Answer (score 1):

I've also done a little digging and as mentioned initially and confirmed by @Aaron, there seems to be no way for an explicitly cancelled `gather()` future to get into a `CANCELLED` state, only `FINISHED`. This seems kind of unintuitive given the official future API of `cancel()` and `cancelled()`, so the question is:

- **Design choice, bug or accepted minor introspection inconvenience for this particular Future subclass. Which one is it? :)**

Below is some more detail, from my digging:

**What seems to happen**

---

Here is [another small snippet](https://gist.github.com/timmwagener/dfed038dc2081c8b5a770e175ba3756b) for testing and reproducing:

- `future_gather.cancel()` cancels `task_child`
- `await future_gather` will cause `task_child` to run and raise `CancelledError`
- `task_child's` done callback for `future_gather` is invoked
- `_done_callback(task_child)` calls `future_gather.set_exception(CancelledError())` which sets:

  - `future_gather._exception` = `CancelledError()`
  - `future_gather._state` = `_FINISHED`
- `await` calls `future_gather.result()` which raises `self._exception` if set *(`CancelledError` in this case)*

**Result**

---

Therefore the end result is a future instance whose:

- `.cancel()` has been called
- has explicitly raised a `CancelledError` to clients
- returns a `CancelledError` for `.exception()`
- **!** returns `False` for `.cancelled()`
- has a `_state` of `FINISHED` *(not `CANCELLED`)*

It seems kinda surprising that an object offering a `cancel()` method would always return `False` for `cancelled()`.

Comment: I looked at the library code for _GatheringFuture.  The constructor defines a variable _cancel_requested, which doesn't actually do anything.  It gets set by the cancel function but is never used.  When that sort of thing happens in my own code, it usually means I got interrupted when I was in the middle of something and forgot to finish it.  I would classify it as a "bug."

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simplified script with the same logic as yours, more or less:

```
#! python3.8

import asyncio

async def main():
    # create tasks and schedule them in gather
    task_child = asyncio.create_task(asyncio.sleep(1.0))
    task_gather = asyncio.gather(task_child)

    print(task_gather.cancel())
    try:
        await task_gather
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        pass
    print(task_child.cancelled(), task_child.done())
    print(task_gather.cancelled(), task_gather.done())

asyncio.run(main())
```

Output:

```
True
True True
False True
```

As you can see, task_gather.cancelled() also returned False in my case.  I think the issue is that cancel() is called before task_gather is awaited (your program does the same thing).  The docs are not clear, I think, about the returned value of cancelled() in that case.  Neither task_child nor task_gather begins to execute until the await statement is encountered, so in effect you are cancelling a Future before it begins.

Note that "task_gather" is not really a Task but a Future.

If I remove the try:except: logic around `await task_gather`, the program aborts with a traceback and only the first print statement is seen.

Comment: Thanks for the simplified version, alot easier and focussed, used it for further testing.